# solr does not search with dot character

Tags: solr

I have a problem with dot searching in solr. For example. I have a product code like:

01.023.0001 
 01.234.0012

and solr does not return any result. What's wrong with my schema ?. Here is my field:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1"  preserveOriginal="1" />
        <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory" dictionary="MORFOLOGIK"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" tokenSeparator=""/> 
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory" dictionary="MORFOLOGIK"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED. Schema change to:**

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1"  preserveOriginal="1" />
    <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory" dictionary="MORFOLOGIK"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" tokenSeparator=""/> 
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory" dictionary="MORFOLOGIK"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
</analyzer>
```

in analyzer "index" i've changed cacenateAll into 1 
in analyzer "query" i'v added solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory filter

Comment: You are saying ".. and solr does not return a result". Which query are running against solr which don't return a result?

Comment: you should specify the solution as an answer so that the question gets resolved